# How to remove the indentation in list of listing

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, indentation, memoir

The list (from `\lstlistoflistings`) is indented compared to list of tables (`\listoftables`). How can I remove the extra indentations?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{The chapter}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={List}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indentation in `listings`' `\lstlistoflistings` resembles that of the LoF/LoT in standard classes. Here's the adaption for `memoir`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@lstlisting}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{The chapter}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={List}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]